# Custom annotation procesor not running

Tags: java, maven, annotations, annotation-processing

I've written an AnnotationProcessor for testing reasons and it is not executed by maven.

I am using google's "auto-service" to create the META-INF data for me.

This is the processor:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({ "test.TestAnnotation" })
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class AnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        this.processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Test");
        return true;
    }

}
```

I've also tried to throw exceptions, create files, running mvnDebug with breakpoints, etc. nothing worked for me.

This is the important part of the project providing the processor (the rest is just groupId, naming, etc.):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
        <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the important part of the POM of the project that is using the annotations for code generation:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>Annotation</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My final goal to let projects add my annotation processor as dependency and its ready to use (kind of like lombok).

**Edit**
The test annotation is in use on a test class.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `proc:none` argument.

It will skip annotation process. So that the `@AutoService` will not work.

Or you can add the java service file manually.

Comment: The annotation is in use (unfortunately I forgot to mention that). The processor is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

So it starts to make sense.

Your compiler plugin setup effectively disables any annotation processing. It's needed, because otherwise the compiler will find the service file, and attempt to load your annotation processor, which is not yet available (it will be just delivered with this module).

But in that case your service file is not generated either. And therefore your processor is not invoked in target module.

In order to fix your problem, you can try using different ways of specifying annotation processors to use.

E.g. you can try to provide annotation processor path (which in turn disables lookup of annotation processors on class path):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <annotationProcessorPath>
                        <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
                        <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-rc4</version>
                    </annotationProcessorPath>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then no `<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>` should be needed.

Comment: Ahoj. That pom will work, without any doubt. (I checked it, it works). But it turns on the Google auto-service processor. (that can be turned on in more simple way, by usual dependency). And the question is how to make work our or customized processor.

Answer (score 0):

This following pom works. Maven is very strict here. No annotationProcessorPaths with Path or annotationProcessorPath in it, no annotationProcessors with annotationProcessor ( these take ready jars, as far as I understood.

```
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration> 
                        <source>10</source>
                        <target>10</target>
                        <outputDirectory>${generatedSources}</outputDirectory>
                        <annotationProcessorPath>
                              <artifactId>processing</artifactId>
                              <name>annotation_processing</name>    
                              <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>                 
                        </annotationProcessorPath>
                    </configuration>
              </plugin>
```

Maven compiled and installed with success.